# test is failing in ~~~Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, testing, backend

```
@Test
fun `makePartialWithdrawal throws exception on minimum remaining balance violation`() {
    val balanceValues = BalanceValues(
        Money.fromCents(10000, Money.Currency.EUR),
        Money.fromCents(9000, Money.Currency.EUR)
    )
    doReturn(balanceValues).`when`(avaloqBalanceClient).getBalanceValues(defaultUserId, accountId)
    val moneyToWithdrawal = Money.fromCents(9500, Money.Currency.EUR)
    val ex = BalanceConditionCheckNotPassedException(defaultUserId, accountId, "failed")
    whenever(withdrawalMinBalanceValidator.checkValidity(defaultUserId, accountId, balanceValues, moneyToWithdrawal)).thenThrow(ex)
    val request = PartialWithdrawalRequest(moneyToWithdrawal)

    assertThrows<BalanceConditionCheckNotPassedException> {
        underTest.makePartialWithdrawal(defaultUserId, accountId, request)
    }

    verify(avaloqBalanceClient).getBalanceValues(defaultUserId, accountId)
}
```

I want to make this test pass.

Comment: What is the error you are seeing? Is it just that the verification fails? Also, what is the code you are testing look like?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.